# How to setup tailwind css for custom-react-app configuration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css

**I'm working on custom-react-app (not create-react-app) and I'm confuse or really don't know how to setup tailwind css in custom-react-app with webpack.**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try npm installation:
npm install tailwindcss

Find file configuration details here:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#create-your-configuration-file

And

You can find complete details here:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: this is for Create-react-app and I'm looking for custom setup . If you can explain custom setup that will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

As per the tailwind documentation:

> Don’t see your favorite tool in the list? We’re always working on new
> guides, but in the mean time you can follow the instructions for
> [installing Tailwind CSS as a PostCSS plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#installing-tailwind-css-as-a-post-css-plugin) instead to get set up
> in no time.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is for Create-react-app and I'm looking for custom setup . If you can explain custom setup that will be appreciated.